# Can a groupoid with at least two objects have a group structure(in a pathological way, if necessary)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, groupoids

A groupoid is defined to be a (small)category where every morphism is an isomorphism. As we know every group can be viewed as as groupoid with a single object. I wonder if the converse of this is also true.

Let $\mathscr C$ be a groupoid containing at least two objects $A,B$. I have a feeling that such a groupoid can never have a group structure(no matter how morphisms in this category are built) since there will be at least two "identity-like" elements $1_A, 1_B$ making trouble in here.

Am I right? If so, how to prove this rigorously(note that rigorously speaking, we haven't even defined the terminology **"viewing a category as a group"**, which is obvious in the case for the groupoid with one object)? If not, what a counterexample will serve the purpose?

Comment: Without giving some definition to the phrase "viewing a category as a group," this question is impossible to answer ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber This is actually part of my question. I also want to see a proper definition.

Comment: What is a proper definition? If you ignore enough of the groupoid's existing structure then you can define things however you want. What do you actually want to know?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Can we safely draw a conclusion that "Under the consensus of mathematicians in the early 21st century, a groupoid with a group structure only has one object"?

Comment: That's not how I would put it. I would say that groups can be identified with groupoids with one object, in the sense that there's an equivalence of categories between the category of groupoids with one object and the category of groups. There is actually a meaningful notion of "groupoid with group structure" which is different from this - you get what is called a 2-group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the multiplication is only partially defined: you can't multiply any two elements of a groupoid. If your groupoid has two objects $A$ and $B$ then you must have identity morphisms $1_A$ and $1_B$. The morphisms $1_A$ and $1_B$ cannot be composed, so the multiplication is not a group multiplication.

Comment: I have some very odd questions. Must we view morphisms in the category as group elements? Must we defined products in the group by the composition of two morphisms? You may want to answer me by saying "Hey, then how would you want to define the group structure if not in this way?", but this is actually the thing I want to ask.(See the bold words in my post)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. We could of course take our groupoid elements $1_A$ and $1_B$ and define a new multiplication $*$ by $1_A * 1_A = 1_A$, $1_A * 1_B = 1_B$, $1_B * 1_A = 1_B$, and $1_B * 1_B = 1_A$. Then we have given our groupoid a group structure, but it is in no way compatible with the groupoid structure.

Comment: Okay, I see. Good example!